# Angular 2 NgFor Regex Message Error - [(ngModel)] works but ngModel is undefined

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, ngfor

I'm trying to have inputs with a regex requirement in a ngFor loop but am getting a "Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined" error where I'm using as the error message that pops up when the page loads.

Here is my code at the moment:

(The keys pipe I have is a custom pipe because item is an object made of objects, so that breaks down the contained objects into key/value pairs.)

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | keys">

  <md-input-container>
    <input
      mdInput
      placeholder={{item.placeholder}}
      name={{item.name}}
      pattern="[\d{7}]*"
      [(ngModel)]="item.value.currentValue"
      #id="ngModel"
    >
  </md-input-container>

  <div 
    [hidden]="id.valid || id.pristine"
  >
    <div [hidden]="!id.hasError('pattern')">
        *Describe required pattern here*
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

From some tutorials I've read (like [this one](http://cuppalabs.github.io/tutorials/how-to-implement-angular2-form-validations/)) I would imagine this would work but I am obviously missing something.

### Edit

Because it was asked for, here is the keys pipe. It is a basic pipe, the like of which can be found all over the internet:

```
  transform(value): any {
    const keys = [];
    for (const key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }

    return keys;
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to validate a 7 digit number? Use `pattern="[0-9]{7}"`

Comment: I was actually wanting to validate against numbers and/or letters but thank you!

Comment: I think it would be helpful to see the "keys" pipe implementation too

Comment: Put your regexp into a regexp tester and see what it tells you and what it matches.

Comment: Just tested it and the regex works fine. The issue is not the regex, the page breaks on load.

Comment: are you sure that ngModel undefined? Because property `value` belongs to `item`. And its always best to show the full line of the error. Just to show everyone because very often people make silly mistakes.

Comment: The regexp `[\d{7}]` means "a single character which is either a digit, a left curly bracket, the number 7, or a right curly bracket".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the elvis operator, like so: `[hidden]="id?.valid || id?.pristine"`